# A problem in secret sharing and mixed operators over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: provable-security, secret-sharing, xor

Recently, I studied an article in which it was written that having $(A-B)\oplus C$ and $B\oplus C$, we cannot find $A$. The authors used this result to build a secret sharing scheme, but they did not provide any proof for this claim. In general case, is this claim correct?

Note that in special cases(as an example, in $GF(2^m)$), we can find $A$ easily(since $A-B=A+B=A\oplus B$).

**Edit:** I don't remember the exact link for my question, but the similar thing is in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025516307319).

Comment: What was the field for this $-$ operation?

Comment: @SEJPM, Integer ring.

Comment: Do you have a link to the article available? (for context)

Comment: "Integer Ring"; is that the ring of integers modulo $n$?  If so, what's $n$?  A power of two?

Comment: @poncho, No, all integer numbers(Z).

Comment: That's strange; for one, you need to define what $\oplus$ does when given a negative integer.  For another, well, in secret sharing schemes, you typically need to derive your secret parameters using an equidistributed probability distribution (as nonuniform distributions tend to leak information); that's actually impossible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @poncho,  It is also strange for me. The correctness of this claim, even for the case of calculations over $\mathbb{N}$ and $A>B$, is also doubtful for me.

Comment: Maybe edit the question to add a reference to the article you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I'll consider that [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used for negative numbers in $\Bbb Z$, or that $A\ge B\ge0$. Even with such provision, the question's claim is too imprecise to be settled:

> having $(A-B)\oplus C$ and $B\oplus C$, we cannot find $A$

Fact is, what we learn about $A$ from $(A-B)\oplus C$ and $B\oplus C$ depends heavily on $D=(A-B)\oplus B$, which we can compute from the givens as $D=((A-B)\oplus C)\oplus(B\oplus C)$ (and this reduction of the two givens to the single $D$ did not change what we can learn from $A$, if nothing was known from $C$ we eliminated).

That information we get on $A$ from $D=(A-B)\oplus B$ varies from

- the low-order bit of $A$, which always matches the low-order bit of $D$;
- to (at least) the low-order $k$ bits of $A$: we can prove by induction that for any integer $k$, $D\equiv-1\pmod{2^k}\implies A\equiv-1\pmod{2^k}$;
- or even the whole of $A$: using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), when $D=-1$, $A$ can only be $-1$ and $B$ can take any value.

A true statement could be: for random choice of the low-order $k$ bits of $A$, $B$ and $C$, probability that we can determine with certainty the low-order $k$ bits of $A$ from $(A-B)\oplus C$ and $B\oplus C$ decrease as $O(2^{-k})$.